# LOTRO Legendary Skills (Champion)

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm a level 40 champion and I've had the books for the legendary skills for about a day of gameplay and I've talked to Gimli, I've read multiple things about people finding every page in a **single** Angmar run, but I haven't had a single page fall for me, What should I do?

Comment: I'm sure you clicked the books to "read" them and got the deeds in your deed log. I hate to say it but sometimes the drop rate sucks for these books. Also keep in mind that the pages only drop from humanoid mobs.

Answer (score 2):

Legendary pages drop of humanoid in different area's. For the first four pages this is Angmar and Eregion, for the second half Misty Mountains and Forochel. You must kill humanoids in at least 2 regions to get all pages. And yes, it does take a while. Just make sure you get them before entering Moria

Answer (score 0):

Those pages drop from enemies scattered across **Angmar, Eregion, and Moria, Forochel, Moria, and the Misty Mountains**, but first you need to talk to the relevant NPC to progress this initial part of the deed quest.

You need to collect 8 pages to earn the legendary traits. The first four pages of a book can be found on enemies scattered across **Angmar, Eregion, and Moria**. The last four pages of a book can be found on enemies scattered across **Forochel, Moria, and the Misty Mountains**.

**Source:** [Lotro Wiki - Legendary Book Pages](https://lotro-wiki.com/index.php/Legendary_Book_Pages)